# Autocomplete выдает значения только по первому слову

Tags: jquery

Подскажите как выводить все значения в массиве, содержащие слово "analyst", в моем примере показывается только значения по первому слову, нужно чтобы показывались все значения содержащие слово "analyst" пример здесь http://jsfiddle.net/UKgD6/246/

```js
var acList = ['smart analyst',
'analyst oversmart',
'smartland analyst',
'undersmart analyst',
'analyst verysmart',
'cool analyst smarter'
];
$('#ac').autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    var matches = $.map( acList, function(acItem) {
      if ( acItem.toUpperCase().indexOf(request.term.toUpperCase()) === 0 ) {
        return acItem;
      }
    });
    response(matches);
  }
```

```html
<input id="ac">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы проверить содержится ли слово в строке вообще, а не только в начале замените условие `=== 0` на `!= -1`

```
if ( acItem.toUpperCase().indexOf(request.term.toUpperCase()) != -1 )
```

[String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf#Checking_occurrences)

Кстати, в данном случае autocomlete работает и [так](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete)

```
var acList = ['smart analyst',
'analyst oversmart',
'smartland analyst',
'undersmart analyst',
'analyst verysmart',
'cool analyst smarter'
];
$('#ac').autocomplete({
  source: acList
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно ))

Comment: За ссылку на адекватный manual по index0f() и lastIndex0f() отдельный респект ))

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить `$.map` на `$.grep`.

Comment: ничего не изменилось.